# Want to prove $\det(P\sigma) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be a permutation matrix.

I'm having trouble trying to prove that $\det(P\sigma) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)$. I think the best way to do this is using the definition of the determinant that involves permutations, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since $\det(P\sigma)=\det(P)\cdot \det(\sigma)$, and the determinant of a permutation matrix can be $\pm 1$, that identity is unlikely to be literally true as asserted. What is really intended?

Comment: I think $\sigma$ is intended to be a subscript.

Comment: Solve it for $\sigma$ a transposition first (in this case, $P_\sigma$ only differs from the identity matrix by swapping two rows).  Then note that $\text{det},$ $\text{sgn},$ and $\sigma \mapsto P_\sigma$ are group homomorphisms (with the appropriate groups)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in

$$\det(P_\sigma)=\sum_{\tau \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\tau)\prod_{i=1}^nP_\sigma(i,\tau_i)$$

only the term corresponding to $\sigma$ is nonzero and equal to $\text{sgn}(\sigma)$.